# Compare cross_val_score before and after log transformation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am playing around with the houseprices dataset from kaggle ([link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques)) and xgboost.

To improve my model, I want to evluate whether it makes sense to perform a log transformation on the target variable (sale prices of houses). I am measuring the performance of my model with neg_mean_absolute_error in cross_val_score. Intuitively, I wanted to perform the inverse transformation on the error, but this doesn't work.

```
# without transformation
cv_score.mean() = -16102.123159086292

# with transformation
y_t = np.log1p(y)
...
cv_score.mean() = -0.08614553190770206
np.exp1p(cv_score.mean()) = -0.08253929830217616
```

Do you have any advice on how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

You should transform back your prediction generated with the model with the transformation.
Then evaluate the model as in the other case

Comment: Is there any way I can formulate this as part of the cross_val_score function? Currently I use:
`xgb_cv = cross_val_score(xgb_model, train_x, train_y,
                             cv=5,
                             scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',
                             fit_params=fit_params)`

Comment: @busy_c Do you mean building your own evaluation metric?